# <> different uses in dart

Tags: dart, generics, types

So I am trying to learn dart, I am not new to programming but I am new to Dart.

Lets say I have this declaration:

```
List<T> nameOfFunction<T> (double variable)
```

I know that the first `List<T>` means, it's the return type of the function. I also know that `double` is the type of the argument taken by the function. But what's new to me is the second `<T>`
What is that for?

Comment: Did you mean for this function to return `List<T>`, or `List<int>` (Dart ints, not the previous generic type also named `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<T>` after `nameOfFunction` is declaring a generic type variable called `T`. The `nameOfFunction` function is generic over all types `T`. That means for every fixed value of `T`, it can return a `List` of `T`.

Though typically having a generic type in the return value only is quite odd, it's not usually useful.

Comment: I modified the post to make it less confusing. You say, It is declaring a generic type. But my question is what variable has that type??? Please be patient with me. I usually know that functions have an input with a type : the arguments and a return with also a type... So what here is of type T? Is it also an argument but with a generic type?!

Comment: The `<T>` introduces a type parameter, making `nameOfFunction` a generic function taking one type argument. Just like `double value` is a value parameter which makes the function take one value argument. Both are *parameters* and must be supplied when the function is called. The function signature here does not *use* that type parameter anywhere (the body might, we can't see that here). A function's type parameter cannot be used outside of that function, its scope is just the function itself.

Comment: So it is a different way to add a local variable of type T? Is there a difference between the declaration above and this one:  list<int> nameOfFuntion(double variable, dynamic secondVariable)     ?

Comment: @lrn "The function signature here does not use that type parameter anywhere" Yes it does, it's used in the return type, at least in the initial formulation

Comment: I can see it has been fixed to say `List<T>` now. The original was `List<int> nameOfFunction<int>(...)` which is indeed the same. I read the question while it said `List<int> nameOfFunction<T>(...)`.

Comment: @lrn I asked op about this, he hasn’t responded yet. Originally he named his generic type “int”. He’s since renamed it T, but it’s not clear if he wanted to return an array of ints, or an array of this generic type (once called int).